# Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make a label display my name, after writing my name in a textbox & then clicking a button

[image]

Each time I run my code I get this error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'messageText'

```
//This button gets info from a Textbox
    private void BtnStrings_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //blz 47
        string firstName;
        string messageText;
        //Fix to my issue

        //==============================
        //Gets the text from the textbox
        //==============================

        firstName = textBox1.Text;

        //MessageBox.Show(messageText + firstName); 

        TextMessage.Text = messageText + firstName;
    }
```

Textmessage is my label, the one that would display my name after clicking the button

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ok, did you spend any time at all looking at anything at all anywhere at all?

Comment: Assign them some default values like: `string firstName = null;` and `string messageText = null;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't assigned anything to `messageText` yet. Simplest fix would be:

```
messageText = "Your name is: ";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already had assigned something to it in the first place, but in my book suddenly that line was deleted so I did the same, and I can't accept your answer in the next 6 minutes because of the (Anti-spam)system these guys use here

Comment: Glad it helped. The error "Use of unassigned local variable" always means the same thing, you're using a variable that doesn't have a value yet.

Answer (score 3):

It writes exactly what it writes:

```
string firstName; 
string messageText;
// for now both of them are "unussigned" - no any value ASSIGNED to them

firstName = textBox1.Text; //now firstname is ASSIGNED - it has certain VALUE
//but messageText still not

TextMessag.Text = messageText + firstName;
// compiler knows that firstName has value, but what is value of messageText???
```

To fix it just write:

```
string firstName = "";
string messageText ="";
// and they will be assigned
```

Answer (score 2):

the reason you are getting this error is because your variable messageText has been declared but it does not have a value. Declaring the variable with the statement

```
string messageText;
```

simply allocates resources for that variable to exist, it does not actually assign a value to that variable.

```
string messageText = "";
```

In the statement above I have declared the variable and I've also assigned it a value. I've assigned it the value of an empty string. Until a variable is assigned a value, it is just 'nothing'. Empty string is 'something', even though it is empty, it can be displayed in a label as no text. You must assign a value to a variable before it can be displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes more & more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string firstName = string.empty;
string messageText = string.empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make messageText empty.

```
string messageText="";
```

then use,

```
TextMessage.Text = messageText + firstName;
```